# Find the A and B matrices for a commutator whose trace is a Fermat-Catalan solution

Tags: matrices, number-theory, matrix-equations

Suppose we have the following matrix:

$M=\begin{pmatrix}2^5 & 7^5 & -3^5\\2^2 & 7^2 & -3^2\\2^4 & 7^4 & -3^4\end{pmatrix}$

The trace of $M$ is the well -known Fermat-Catalan solution:

$2^5+7^2-3^4=0$

By the Albert-Muckenhoupt theorem, we have

$M=AB-BA$

We also know by FLT that the first and third row sums of  $M$ are not zero.

How do you find an $A$ and $B$ that will give you this particular $M$?

Comment: This is the most ridiculous "application" of FLT I've ever seen.

Comment: Then
in 1994, Laffey and Reams  showed that every matrix in $M_n( \mathbb Z)$
 with trace zero
is a commutator. In 2016 Stasinski  proved that every
matrix in
$M_n(  P)$
 for
$P$
a principal ideal ring, with trace zero is a commutator

Comment: http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2016-368-04/S0002-9947-2015-06402-2/   ..........................  https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.6872

Comment: FLT does not apply to the second row.  The row sum is simply non-zero if calculated. LHS is $53$.  RHS is $-9$, so the row sum is $44$.  FLT is not needed at all, but it avoids having to compute the first and third row sums. Using FLT, you can just glance at the exponents.

Comment: I was able to get the Laffey and Reams paper, but not the Stasinski.  We know from these theorems that the commutator exists, but how do they help solve for $A$ and $B$ for the given matrix $M$?

Comment: Using FLT because it avoids a trivial computation is simply absurd. Most mathematicians will never be able to understand all the mathematics involved in the proof of that result, while my nephew can compute powers and sums.

Comment: Whether or not one uses FLT is a red herring.  Rather than absurd, why not just think of it as convenient overkill.  I don't have any issues with not using FLT to think about the row sums.  The real question stems from the proven fact that $A$ and $B$ should be solvable from this $M$, but how? What approach or theorems are recommended?

Comment: I don't know how the articles help. If I thought it important, I would try computer runs for this. However, I would begin with  trace free examples with much smaller numbers. I would keep to 3 by 3 matrices, evidently there are some thing that change between dimension 2 and dimension 3....Let's see, i did think it necessary that mathematicians reading this be aware that existence had been proved over the ring of integers, not just over the reals or rationals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We consider the equation $(*) \;AB-BA=M$, where the unknowns are the $18$ entries of $A,B$. Since the function $f:(A,B)\in M_3\times M_3\rightarrow AB-BA\in \{Z\in M_3;tr(Z)=0\}$ is surjective, the derivative of $f$ has rank $8$. That is, the general solution  of $(*)$ has $18-8=10$ free parameters. It remains to know what are these $10$ paremeters and how to choose them, depending on whether we want a solution in i) a real algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ or ii) in $\mathbb{Q}$ or iii) in $\mathbb{Z}$.

When one has Maple, the least tiring is to consider the case i), using the Grobner basis theory. The shape of a Grobner basis lets you guess a choice of parameters; then we give simple values to these parameters. For instance, we obtain the following -in Maple format- in a real algebric extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $3$.

A= Matrix(3, 3, [[8, 1, (71723588976/3027762184027595)*c[3, 3]^2+(2984407072706366/15138810920137975)*c[3, 3]-14832628576459297/2162687274305425], [0, (49493708273997/5817888290354509901)*c[3, 3]^2+(578526588058455697/8311268986220728430)*c[3, 3]+6757362833635887381/1187324140888675490, -(162059734160351703/488906242479941239530535)*c[3, 3]^2-(13367942213184840085621/4889062424799412395305350)*c[3, 3]-124833447963523709485393/698437489257058913615050], [0, 0, 0]])

B= Matrix(3, 3, [[-(216984194154/8827294997165)*c[3, 3]^2-(8918857908851339/44136474985825)*c[3, 3]-431960743222798959/44136474985825, 0, 0], [(143447177952/3027762184027595)*c[3, 3]^2+(5968814145412732/15138810920137975)*c[3, 3]+39540735624855006/2162687274305425, 0, 0], [-2, (1898166816/1765458999433)*c[3, 3]^2+(77630790402871/8827294997165)*c[3, 3]-5307136376915304/8827294997165, c[3, 3]]])

where $c[3,3]$ is a root of the equation

$593177130c[3, 3]^3+4879962476371c[3, 3]^2+66387355284897c[3, 3]-8152887366719494 = 0$.

EDIT 1. If we choose $c[3,3]\approx 34.57\cdots$, then we obtain

$A\approx \begin{pmatrix}8& 1&-0.0144322399335206621\\0& 8.1079935808833385963& -.27366129513717087073\\0& 0& 0\end{pmatrix}$,

$B\approx \begin{pmatrix}-16802.729776638927233& 0& 0\\31.971135520132958675& 0& 0\\-2& -295.88084599083230019& 34.573449979585872872\end{pmatrix}$.

Now if you want some solution of type iii) (To do what ?...), then follow the advice of Will Jagy: roll up your sleeves.

EDIT 2. Below, the OP found a couple solution in $M_3(\mathbb{Q})$ that depends on a parameter $a_{3,2}$ -I don't know how he did it, but he did it!-

Curiously , the system "mod(221)": $191a_{3,2}-933230=0,5(5a_{3,2}-3066)=0$ has the solution $a_{3,2}=127$. Thus, we obtain an explicit solution over $\mathbb{Z}$.

$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&-4113& 81\\1& -55& 0\\0& 127& -27\end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}0& 49& -9\\0& -4& 0\\1& -43& 0\end{pmatrix}$.

EDIT 3. Comment on the OP's EDIT 1. We must not look for an explicit formula; it is very easy to find a solution over $\mathbb{Z}$  for $p>q,r,x,y,z$ given in $\mathbb{N}^*$. For example, let $p=13,q=9,r=12,x=5,y=8,z=10$. Resuming your choice, the unknown is the second column of $A$: $[w,v,u]^T$. Equality $M=AB-BA$ gives two affine relations where $w,v$ depend on $u$. It remains to obtain integers solutions of the previous system. Here a solution is

$u=305711831847240,v=2446234370904,w=156231348839563264$.

Comment: I used a value of $c[3,3] = 4.35222$ approximately, and checked a couple of values of $M$.  It looks correct!

Comment: No, the positive root is $\approx 34.57$; cf my edit.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the correction. I made an arithmetic mistake in the calculation.

Comment: When I plug your value for $u=305711831847240$ into my "explicit" formulas, I get the values for $v$ and $w$ exactly!  Could you elaborate on how you got $u=305711831847240$?

Answer (score 1):

Poking around on my TI nSpire CX calculator, I came up with a more exact solution for A and B.

$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & (191a_3{_2}-933230)/221 & 81\\1 & 5(5a_3{_2}-3066)/221 & 0\\0 & a_3{_2} & -27\end{pmatrix}$

$B=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 49 & -9\\0 & -4 & 0\\1 & -43 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

I tested $a_3{_2}$ with some integers, rationals, and even $a_3{_2}=\pi$ .

Always works fine.

EDIT $1$:

Thanks to loup blanc above for the $\mathbb{Z}$ solution of $a_3{_2}=127.$

I have taken the solution even further on the calculator to come up with an exact solution for the following generalized commutator:

$M=\begin{pmatrix}z^r-y^q & y^p & -z^p\\x^q & y^q & -z^q\\x^r & y^r & -z^r\end{pmatrix}$

Notice that unless Beal's Conjecture is false, the upper left hand corner can never be $x^p$ when $p,q,r\geq3$.

The solution for $A$ and $B$ using the same $a_3{_2}$ system is:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & f_1(a_3{_2}) & z^r\\1 & f_2(a_3{_2}) & 0\\0 & a_3{_2} & -z^{p-q}\end{pmatrix}$

$B=\begin{pmatrix}0 & y^q & -z^q\\0 & -x^q & 0\\1 & -(z^qx^r+z^p)z^{-q}& 0\end{pmatrix}$

The $f_1(a_3{_2})$ and $f_2(a_3{_2})$ are extremely long expressions.

EDIT $2$:

Continuing my efforts on the TI nSpire CX calculator, I came up with a much simpler solution for $A$ and $B$ in the original Fermat-Catalan case that does not depend on $a_3{_2}$.

$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -18464/5 & 81\\1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 3066/5 & -27\end{pmatrix}$

$B=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 49 & -9\\0 & -4 & 0\\1 & -43 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

To do this I used $\vec{v}=(x,y,z,p,q,r)=(2,7,3,5,2,4)$ in the following general solutions for $A$ and $B$.

$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & f_1(\vec{v}) & z^r\\1 & 0 & 0\\0 & f2(\vec{v}) & -z^{p-q}\end{pmatrix}$

$B=\begin{pmatrix}0 & y^q & -z^q\\0 & -x^q & 0\\1 & -(z^qx^r+z^p)z^{-q}& 0\end{pmatrix}$

where $f_1(\vec{v})=-((z^rx^q-z^p)z^qx^r+z^{2q}y^r+z^{p+r}x^q+z^qy^px^q-z^{2p})z^{-q}/(x^{2q}+z^q)$

and $f_2(\vec{v})=((z^{q+r}+z^px^q)z^qx^r-z^{2q}y^rx^q+z^{p+q+r}+z^{2p}x^q+z^{2q}y^p)z^{-2q}/(x^{2q}+z^q)$

Notice that both $f_1(\vec{v})$ and $f_2(\vec{v})$ share the same common denominator!

This same method works for finding $A$ and $B$ for the commutator constructed for Darmon-Granville solutions such as the following $\vec{v}=(x,y,z,p,q,r)=(2,13,5,5,3,5)$.  The upper left hand corner in this case is populated by $928$ which factors into $29\cdot2^5$ as expected.